# Playing Music in Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I want to access the frequencies one by one from the list of frequencies(Frtm) and want to store them in a signal and at the end i want to play them ...
I have written this code but i don't know where is the problem if anyone one can help then it will be appreciated.

```
    function Music3 ()
      Fs = 44100;
      T = 1 / Fs;
t = 0:1 / 18:5;
      M = zeros (1, 88);
      for I = 7:88

        M (I) = round (36.8 * (2 ^ (1 / 12)) ^ (I - 6));
      endfor
      Signal = [];
      FrTm = [50, 3; 50, 3; 52, 3; 54, 3; 50, 3; 54, 3; 52, 3; 45, 3; 50, 3; 50, 3; 52, 3; 54, 3; 50, 6; 49, 3; 1, 3; 50, 3; 50, 3; 52, 3; 54, 3; 55, 3; 54, 3; 52, 3; 50, 3; 49, 3; 45, 3; 47, 3; 49, 3; 50, 6; 50, 3; 1, 3; 47, 5; 49, 1; 47, 3; 45, 3; 47, 3; 49, 3; 50, 3; 1, 3; 45, 5; 47, 1; 45, 3; 43, 3; 42, 6; 45, 3; 1, 3; 47, 5; 49, 1; 47, 3; 45, 3; 47, 3; 49, 3; 50, 3; 47, 3; 45, 3; 50, 3; 49, 3; 52, 3; 50, 6; 50, 6];
      for i = 1:length (FrTm)
        M (i) = FrTm (i);
        New = M (i);
        data = sin (2 * pi * New / Fs * t);
        Signal = [data; Signal];
      endfor
      stem(Signal);

      sound(Signal,44100);
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you want:

```
clear; clc; close all;

Fs = 44100;
T = 1 / Fs;
sin_time_seconds = 1
t = 0:T:sin_time_seconds;
Signal = [];
FrTm = 10*[50, 3; 50, 3; 52, 3; 54, 3; 50, 3; 54, 3; 52, 3; 45, 3; 50, 3; 50, 3; 52, 3; 54, 3; 50, 6; 49, 3; 1, 3; 50, 3; 50, 3; 52, 3; 54, 3; 55, 3; 54, 3; 52, 3; 50, 3; 49, 3; 45, 3; 47, 3; 49, 3; 50, 6; 50, 3; 1, 3; 47, 5; 49, 1; 47, 3; 45, 3; 47, 3; 49, 3; 50, 3; 1, 3; 45, 5; 47, 1; 45, 3; 43, 3; 42, 6; 45, 3; 1, 3; 47, 5; 49, 1; 47, 3; 45, 3; 47, 3; 49, 3; 50, 3; 47, 3; 45, 3; 50, 3; 49, 3; 52, 3; 50, 6; 50, 6];
for i = 1:length (FrTm)
    data = sin (2 * pi .* FrTm(i) .* t);
    Signal = [Signal data];
end
plot(Signal);

sound(Signal,Fs);
```

I multiplied the frequencies by 10 else they were too low.

`sin_time_seconds` is the time you want each sound to be displayed. There were many errors in your script, especially with the dimensions of the vectors you created.

Comment: No problem. Can you upvote and accept the solution? Thank you.